# Invoking MVC Controller inside Azure worker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly. I have a MVC controller action that I need to call periodically. I am trying to create a scheduler with Quartz.net and then I need to run that scheduler in my worker. How can I access my MVC controller action inside my worker role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an HTTP request to the action's route URL from the worker role.

```
using (var httpClinet = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = httpClient.DownloadString("http://www.site.com/path/to/action");
}
```

**Update**

> ...how I can get the current url inside worker role? Because the url
>   would change depending on where it is being deployed...

One way would be to store the variable URL segments in your worker role's `ConfigurationSettings`.

```
<Role name="My.WorkerRole">
    ...
    <ConfigurationSettings>
        <Setting name="UrlScheme" value="https" />
        <Setting name="UrlHost" value="www.site.com" />
        <Setting name="UrlPath" value="path/to/action?param1=value1" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    ...
</Role>

using (var httpClinet = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}",
        RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("UrlScheme"),
        RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("UrlHost"),
        RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("UrlPath"));
    var result = httpClient.DownloadString(url);
}
```

You can then change the values in your `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file before deploying.

Comment: That is great. Any idea how I can get the current url inside worker role? Because the url would change depending on where it is being deployed...